# Draw Text in Background thread ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, grand-central-dispatch

## What I'm trying to Accomplish

I have a UICollectionView in which I'm trying to render all of the drawing in the background, then display when finished with a fade in animation.

I'm already doing this well with Images, but some of the drawing is text only.  I need to size the size the text appropriately then draw it in the background.

It's potentially a lot of text and creates stuttering when done on main thread.

## How I'm trying to do it

I was using `CGBitmapContextCreate` for images, so I tried to do it with text as well:

```
-(void)drawTextFromBundle
{
     UIFont * font = [UIFont AvenirLTStdBlackObliqueWithSize:35]; //custom font

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
         CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
         CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, 250, backgroundHeight - 112, 8, 250 * 4, colorSpaceRef, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);
         CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
         [_text drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, backgroundHeight - 112) withFont:font];
          CGImageRef outputImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
          imageRef = outputImage;
         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(finishDrawingImage) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
         CGContextRelease(context);
         CGImageRelease(outputImage);
   });
}
```

## Details

This is obviously not a right way to do it because I'm getting many errors, all involving Core Graphics text functions, similar to `<Error>: CGContextSetFont: invalid context 0x0`

I know there is `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` but I wasn't sure if this was thread safe, as I've heard it wasn't.

To note, this method is indeed getting called from within a `-drawRect:` method. The same exact context parameters are working for my images.

What can I do to get the text drawn to any customization I want, all done safely in the background? Bonus points if you can tell me how to do it while shrinking the text to fit the appropriate size.

Thanks again SO team.

Comment: Don't try to do drawing/manipulate the UI from a background thread. Graphics operations typically must take place on the main thread.

Comment: Almost positive as of iOS 4 UI can be drawn in background

Comment: Offscreen drawing should definitely be done on a background thread, but no way can you start that background thread from your drawRect method. DrawRect must draw stuff that is already waiting to be drawn and exit quickly. It's context is only valid until drawRect returns (I'm scared to think what your finishDrawingImage method does - maybe you could post more code?)

Comment: finishDrawingImage simply adds the finished image to an imageview then calls a delegate method sayings its ready for display.  The method is used outside of drawRect method as well.

Answer (score -1):

When you change the UI , you need in the main thread (main queue).

try to put the below in the main queue

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, 250, backgroundHeight - 112, 8, 250 * 4, colorSpaceRef, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_text drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, backgroundHeight - 112) withFont:font];
        CGImageRef outputImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
        imageRef = outputImage;
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(finishDrawingImage) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    });

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGImageRelease(outputImage);
});
```

Comment: You didn't updated your UI with newly rendered `outputImage`. You just created it and sent a message `finishDrawingImage` to your `self` object, which is just a sort of notification callback. You better add the `outputImage` as a `withObject` parameter to that method. Also, I  would avoid using `performSelectorOnMainThread` by writing just `[self finishDrawingImage:outputImage];`